# Linq group by month

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a table with a date field and time field.I want to retrieve a result set grouped by the month and the number of records that appear within that month. How can this be done in LINQ?
Something like this.

Data.

10/10/2011        *00:00:10:000* 
10/11/2011        *00:00:20:000* 
11/01/2011        *00:00:10:000* 
11/10/2011        *00:00:40:000*

I want to retrieve

10/1/2011        *00:00:30:000*
11/1/2011        *00:00:50:000*

Thank`s for help.

i am try something like this.

```
var monthely = 
  from u in sqlDataContract.TimeTrickTables 
  group u by u.EntryDate.Value.Month into g 
  select new 
  { 
    EntryDate = g.Key, 
    ETime = g.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (subtotal, t) => subtotal.Add((TimeSpan)t.ETime)) 
  };
```

but it throw this Exception  **The query operator 'Aggregate' is not supported**

Comment: Custom aggregates are not supported by Linq2SQL. Se my update.

Answer (score 5):

```
from u in TimeTrickTables
group u by u.EntryDate.Value.Month into g
select new
{
    Month = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count(), //Nr. of records
    Time = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.ETime.Ticks)) //Total time
}
```

Comment: try `new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.ETime.Ticks))`